# From array choose one value to use as key and group by that value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, lodash

I have an array of objects. I want to group the objects by a value and then use that value as a key for the rest of the values in that object.

For example I have array like this:

```json
{
  0: {prize: "Foo", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith"},
  1: {prize: "Foo", first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Smith"},
  2: {prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe"},
  3: {prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Jones"},
  4: {prize: "Foo", first_name: "Judy", last_name: "Alvarez"},
}
```

And my desired outcome is something like this:

```json
{
  Foo: [
   {first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith"},
   {first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Smith"},
   {first_name: "Judy", last_name: "Alvarez"}
  ],
  Bar: [
   {first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe"}, 
   {first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Jones"}
  ]
}
```

I'm using TypeScript and the closest I got was using this code snippet I found:

```js
console.log(
  _.chain(res.data)
  .groupBy("prize")
  .map((value: any, key: any) => ({prize: key, winners: value}))
  .value()
);
```

Which gave me an outcome like this:

```json
[
  0: {
      prize: "Foo", 
      winners: [
       {prize: "Foo", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith"}, 
       {prize: "Foo", first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Smith"},
       {prize: "Foo", first_name: "Judy", last_name: "Alvarez"}
      ]
     },
  1: {
      prize: "Bar", 
      winners: [
       {prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe"}, 
       {prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Jones"}
      ]
     },
]
```

How would I modify my code to achieve the format I need effectively? I'm not even completely sure I'm on the right track, maybe the code needs to be completely changed?

This seems like a quite common problem and has probably been answered before but because I have a hard time even describing what I want, I couldn't find anything. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14446511, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40774697, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51852427, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36955906.

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure the object and group by `prize` in a single loop.

```js
const
    data = [{ prize: "Foo", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith" }, { prize: "Foo", first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Smith" }, { prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe" }, { prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Jones" }, { prize: "Foo", first_name: "Judy", last_name: "Alvarez" }],
    result =  data.reduce(
        (r, { prize, ...rest }) => ((r[prize] ??= []).push(rest), r),
        {}
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the original object using `for...in` and since you're using the `prize` property as the new key for the new object you can store the object (that will be put in the key's array) as a variable called `t` and store the key as a variable `k`.

```
 var k = obj[i].prize
 var t = obj[i]
```

See the snippet below for a working example.

```js
var obj = {
  0: {prize: "Foo", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith"},
  1: {prize: "Foo", first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Smith"},
  2: {prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe"},
  3: {prize: "Bar", first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Jones"},
  4: {prize: "Foo", first_name: "Judy", last_name: "Alvarez"},
}

const constructObj = () =>{
  var newObj = {}
  
  for (var i in obj){
    var k = obj[i].prize
    var t = obj[i]
    //remove below line to include all keys
    delete t.prize
    if (newObj[k]){
      var vals = newObj[k]
      vals.push(t)
    } else {
      newObj[k] = [t]
    }
  }
  return newObj
};

var final = constructObj()

console.log(final)
```

Comment: This is much longer and frankly uglier than a lot of the code presented in the answers to the duplicates.

Comment: @Aplet123 I was writing the answer when you commented and did not see them. If there is a better answer so be it but I don't think it warrants a downvote since the question itself was structured well, had all pertinent information included (including code snippet) and provided a feasible solution.